# Keras RNN LSTM accuracy not changing

Tags: python, keras, lstm

**X_train**

```
[[0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

**y_train**

```
1
1
1
0
0
1
```

The third and 4th column in X_train are a clear indicator of the output. I am trying out RNN with LSTM so I have chosen this sample data and I want to overfit this.

The accuracy is not changing at all even after **50** epochs of training -

```
Epoch 1/60
6/6 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 5.3141 - acc: 0.6667
Epoch 2/60
6/6 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 5.3141 - acc: 0.6667
Epoch 3/60
6/6 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 5.3141 - acc: 0.6667
Epoch 4/60
6/6 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 5.3141 - acc: 0.6667
Epoch 5/60
6/6 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 5.3141 - acc: 0.6667
```

**Model**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_length,batch_input_shape=( batch_size, input_dim)))
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

**Parameters**

```
MAX_NB_WORDS = 10
embedding_vecor_length = 32
max_length = 10
batch_size = 2
input_dim = max_length
```

I am using Theano backend. Probably something missing very obvious. Please help!

**UPDATE**

Apologies for providing half baked stuff. I am compiling the model thus -

```
opt = SGD(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

print np.shape(X_train)

callbacks = [
            # EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, verbose=2),
            RemoteMonitor(root='http://localhost:9000'),
            ModelCheckpoint(filepath="/tmp/weights.hdf5", monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto')
        ]

print X_train
print y_train

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=60, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks) #, validation_data=(X_val, y_val)
```

**UPDATE2**

Rectified this by changing the activation function from 'softmax' to 'sigmoid'
A proper explanation is missing. I guess the "why" should be the answer not the how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before training a model, you need to configure the learning process, which is done using the 'compile' method - model.compile()

Then for training your model, you will have to use the  'fit' method - model.fit()

Please read more below:

https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/

Okey after you've added more information I've run some test. First I've added one more row to X_train, and y_train

```
X_train = 
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

y_train = [[1],[1],[1],[0],[0],[1],[1]]
```

also changed batch_size to 1.

and the result was not a surprise:

```
Epoch 59/60
1/7 [===>..........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1921e-07 - acc: 1.0000
2/7 [=======>......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000    
3/7 [===========>..................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.3141 - acc: 0.6667
4/7 [================>.............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.9856 - acc: 0.7500
5/7 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.1885 - acc: 0.8000
6/7 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.3141 - acc: 0.6667
7/7 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 4.5550 - acc: 0.7143
```

In every Epoch the 7/7 step was always the same acc: 0.7143 but others (1/7, 2/7 and so on) was rather random. My answer is:

You do not have enough data to train the model. On this data set, netowork tends to find the best solution in such a few steps that outcome will always be the same. In this case, a result will never be worth anything. I might be wrong, but try to test it with hundreds/thousands of data

Comment: I am compiling and fitting the model. Updated question please check @Byte_me

Comment: sounds good...also I realized there was the learning rate...setting it 0.1 for so small data made it move...my initial learning rate was 0.01